# Cannot receive UPower signals

Tags: 12.10, c, dbus

I am newbie in dbus, so please be patient with me.

I have a following code:
http://pastebin.com/8zpM7Pwb.

It is some sample I found and changed to suit my case.

General idea is to 'trap' dbus signals from `com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service` and from `org.freedesktop.UPower` (mainly the second one - I use Panel only as comparison). The problem is that I am receiving Unity Panel signals, but none from UPower. I did launch `dbus-monitor` in second terminal in the same time, so I know for sure, that those signals do fly around.

I did also testing on those interfaces one by one and the result is the same - code with Unity Panel interface gets signals I want, code with UPower doesn't - it simply blocks on `dbus_connection_read_write(conn, -1);` and never goes on.

Can anyone show me where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `DBUS_BUS_SESSION` I should have used `DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM`, as interface `org.freedesktop.UPower` doesn't send signals in session scope.

As simple as that.